# Setting a UIButton alpha is not working correctly on iOS 7.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am disabling and changing the alpha of a `UIButton` back and forth and when the method is called it enables the button the alpha never changes.

The code below is in the actual ViewController that contains the button. But I am calling these methods from a different ViewController that is showing this ViewController.

```
-(void)enableArrow {

    [self.LocationCirlceButton setEnabled:YES];
    [self.LocationCirlceButton setAlpha:1.0f];

}

-(void)disableArrow {
    [self.LocationCirlceButton setEnabled:NO];
    [self.LocationCirlceButton setAlpha:0.5f];
}
```

And, yes this UI work is being done on the main thread.

Comment: By any chance is the button hidden initially?

Comment: what kind of uibutton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue but it is very weird. I had the following image set for disabled, but this file somehow was deleted from the app. So I changed it to the `Checkmark_normal` file and it all works.

```
 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_disabled.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

**Now:**

```
 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: It's not weird. When `UIImageView` or `UIButton` or any container of `UIImage` can't find the specified image then it always shows container's `background color`. I guess you had the background color as `[UIColor clearColor]`.

Comment: But it was showing one of the other icons normal or selected. It wasn't showing nothing, but either the normal or selected image.

Answer (score 0):

How about make that `UIButton` as a public property and create methods in `that different ViewController`, not the `ViewController contains the button` ?

Like this:

```
-(void) enableButton
{
    [originalController.button setAlpha:1.0f];
}

-(void)disableButton
{
    [originalController.button setAlpha:0.0f];
}
```

The key is you have to grab that particular `ViewController contains the button` in order to make this works (many ways to do that).

Answer (score 0):

There are two subviews to control. You can call

```
myButton.imageView.alpha = 0.5;
myButton.titleLabel.alpha = 0.5;
```

or you can subclass button and override `setEnabled:`

```
-(void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled
{
    super.enabled = enabled;
    self.imageView.alpha = enabled ? 1 : 0.5;
    self.titleLabel.alpha = self.imageView.alpha;
}
```